# Typescript - How to make values to equal the keys of an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to type an object where the key and value are the same:

```js
const myObj = {
    FOO: 'FOO',
    BAR: 'BAR'
};
```

I tried setting up `typeof` with `myObj`, and with the `key`:

```js
const actions: { [x: string]: x } = { // 'x' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof x'?
    set: 'set1'
}

const actions: { [x: string]: typeof x } = {
    set: 'set1'  // doesn't trigger
}

const actions: { [p: string]: keyof typeof actions } = {
    set: 'set' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}

type K = 'set' | 'set2';
const actions: { [p in K]: K } = { // triggers missing set2
    set: 'set1' // doesn't trigger
}
```

Is there a way I can make sure the key and value match all the time? TIA!

Comment: There is the `Set` object which only has key property which you also use as a value

Comment: @Berkays Can you please provide an example? I haven't used Set in typescript before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it after playing with for a while:

```js
type K = 'set' | 'set2';
const actions: { [p in K]: p } = { // note that I am using p instead of K from the question
    set: 'set1'
}
```

With this setup I get the following errors:

```
TS2741: Property 'set2' is missing in type '{ set: "set"; }' but required in type '{ set: "set"; set2: "set2"; }'.

TS2322: Type '"set1"' is not assignable to type '"set"'.
```

And following is what makes it happy:

```js
type K = 'set' | 'set2';
const actions: { [p in K]: p } = {
    set: 'set',
    set2: 'set2'
}
```

UPDATE: This works if you have a known list of keys, but if you have an unknown list of keys or to match any key to its value, please follow @sno2 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70643986/1741094)

Comment: I'd like a solution that's less redundant (only write each key once).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a helper function that takes in your object then does a TypeScript check on it by generating extra parameters that would make your code fail if the given object does not pass our same key/value law.

```
// basically, we create an extra parameter when the object is not valid
function createSamePairedObject<T extends Readonly<Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>>>(obj: T, ..._lockParams: T extends { [K in keyof T]: K } ? [] : ["INVALID_PAIRED_OBJECT"]): T {
  return obj as any;
}

// PASS
const a = createSamePairedObject({ // { readonly a: "a" }
  a: "a",
} as const);

// FAIL - "b" != "bb"
const b = createSamePairedObject({
  a: "a",
  b: "bb",
} as const);

// FAIL - not const object
const c = createSamePairedObject({
  [5]: 5,
});

// PASS
const d = createSamePairedObject({
  [5]: 5,
} as const);
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECMEMGcEsGNIBskE8A0oDuBTU8AnHSAFz0gDtQcAPEgyUAB0gYFscyDsALHKkn1AB7cACsc8EqFjRQFYdIBuyWABMAUADMArhSmxhVQsTIBlSBwAKkWETUB5cZJIAeACrU6-NXIBKxGpGaK4B8MIEaq5WBMJMOAQkqADSOBigMXEJSamoAHwFABSiYgBcoO6YAHQ1APpIwvAA1jbs0OWetGQUvqAA3qAA2skyVE1pwloVALrlIwC+oAD8Q9Og5YMARACSAHIAagCCADLbACK1VofbfgCiFw4AQgBStwDC7pvTAJQd-RqgUBEEg6AhUEqgGCQiioADcGnmGg0IAyhzMZg04Qo0GkjAAvPgiKQcBZrLZ7E4JFJCgMUQMiUEKGhIeVNpBNqBEYDIKz2egEZC5Ficd94ciwAAxa7HUAAWlAm3AHIAhATFUrMUYcRBQASTMTSTgbHYcI5nNS+gCWQq+VbwKzwEr+YsocKSKKkSipdsZfKFNI3SJzSRNdiA7rCaYSZYjeTTZSXDSrYMAKyzUAp50e8Wo9Gh7VqCP68wx40U4NJwGp9OZgWurXu2FAA)

Comment: isn't running a function just for type checking overkill? typescript is supposed to be static, but with functions, I will be wasting CPU cycles at runtime unnecessarily ..

Comment: @GopikrishnaS Perhaps, but this is the best solution to your question IMO. Another way would be to use type asserts which would not effect runtime but that would be pretty ugly. In my benchmarks, it seems most JS engines optimize functions that take a single parameter and then return it as the map function is getting +-5% compared to the regular object approach so it should have virtually no effect on your code.  https://jsbench.me/enky7kb166/1

Comment: I guess it makes sense if you have an unknown list of keys

Comment: @GopikrishnaS no, it should make sense in all cases as you don't need to update your list of keys every time you add a new one. It automatically updates based upon your code.

Comment: I can't seem to fix the second example. Even after changing the `b` to `bb` I still get an error: `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.  Arguments for the rest parameter '_lockParams' were not provided`

Comment: "wasting CPU cycles at runtime unnecessarily" If you care about CPU cycles wasted by a small identity function then you are either prematurely optimizing or something very strange is happening with your code.  Your JS runtime would probably automatically optimize away such a function call if it decides that doing so would improve performance significantly; if your JS runtime is unable to optimize things like that then a single identity function is likely the least of your problems.  There might be reasons to avoid identity functions but CPU cycles shouldn't be one of them.

Comment: @GopikrishnaS I have fixed it now. I was checking the key union vs the value union when I should have been iterating each.

Comment: Would be excellent to be able to do this w/out the redundant key/value.